# Combined regular expression with condition

Tags: java, regex

I have a lines like below

```
Line 1 -> jsyw0wjsdn //XYZ S ckdisd89dmsi
Line 2 -> jdfhajh8nfdurye /* XYZ  S kldfifiejwem */ sjdbsksdk
```

If you see this lines I am interested in matching this pattern:

```
(.*?)//\\s*XYZ\\s*S(.*?)
```

...or this pattern:

```
(.*?)/\\*//s*XYZ\\s*S(.*?)\\*/.*?
```

Is there a way I could combine both of them and write simple regex? Taking both regex and combine with `|` (OR) is not an option I am looking for. Something like below:

```
(.*?)//\\s*XYZ\\s*S(.*?) | (.*?)/\\*//s*XYZ\\s*S(.*?)\\*/.*?
```

I wanted a combined regex which matches any of the 2 lines (line1 and line2).

Comment: What is expected output?. Also you don't have to *capture* string if you are trying to `match` them

Comment: I wanted a combined regex which matches any of the 2 lines(line1 and line2)

Comment: What exactly do you want to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `OR` 2 subpatterns, use a pipe symbol `|`. See **[alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)**.

The regex `foo|bar` matches either `foo` or `bar`.

The regex `Stack(?:Overflow|Exchange)` matches either `StackOverflow` or `StackExchange`.